# Java, JNI and C++: How do I generate a header file from native method declarations?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Java, JNI and C++: How do I generate a header file from native method declarations?

I have Java project, which communicates with C++ code through JNI.
The challenge is now I need to add new methods. I first started by declaring
the native methods in the java code. Now I need to regenerate the header file
for the JNI methods. I work in Eclipse, not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can use the command line tool javah, that is distributed with the jsdk. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javah.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to do it using command line.

- go to the source file directory.
- `javac  filename.java` to generate `filename.class` file.
- `javah  filename` to generate `filename.h` file.

You may refer to [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) and [javah](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javah.html) for more help.

Answer (score 3):

This is not built into Eclipse but it is easy to do:

1. Go `File » New... » XML File` to create an Ant file (code below) in your project.
2. Go `Project » Properties » Builders » New... » Ant Builder` to add the Ant file as a build step. Set Refresh to "project" so that generated files show up in the project. Be sure to put the build step after the Java Builder step because `javah` reads compiled `class` files.

Now, you'll always have up-to-date header files whenever you change your Java code. You just have list the applicable classes in the Ant file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="javah">
    <mkdir dir="javah" />

    <javah classpath="bin" destdir="javah">
        <!-- list classes here -->
        <class name="com.example.MyClass" />
    </javah>
</project>
```

You can get a lot more sophisticated in the Ant script but the above is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

What about this utility in the JDK? 
javah