# how to call javah from ADT ide

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, java-native-interface

[image: screenshot]

Took the basic example from NDK.
Added a function, which doesn't exist yet at native side.
Now I am looking a way to call `javah` from ADT IDE and expect to be generated the function header to my file, near the others:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint width, jint height);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_step(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj);
}
;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint width, jint height) {
    setupGraphics(width, height);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_step(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
    renderFrame();
}
```

at least to `extern "C"` section.

Is there any way to do it? What is the best practice?

- generate with a tool to **gl2jni.cpp** than Cut and Paste to **gl_code.cpp**, to keep the existing code in gl_code.cpp ? - or do I miss a basic environment setup?

Do I need to write some build configuration? - like always generate those headers to an empty file?

Is there any plugin which can do it from IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the Eclipse IDE, running `javah` can be easily automated to put header files anywhere you want them whenever your Java code is compiled. See my answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863610/2226988).

Comment: +1, for effort, but ant build.xml is called AFTER navive library build, in the java build process. At least it will generate the headers needed to a file..